# Unable to connect printer connected to bridge network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer

My PC and printer are connected to a wifi router operating in the bridge mode. This router is in turn connected to a central router (operating in normal mode) through a LAN cable.

Both Printer and PC have the same default gateway (192.168.1.1) and different IP addresses (PC on 192.168.1.104 and Printer on 192.168.1.111). I can ping the printer as well from the PC.

But I cannot connect to the printer. Neither does it show in the list of network devices. What am I doing wrong? My PC is running Windows 10 and printer is Canon Pixma MX410.

Comment: When you say you cannot connect to the printer, what are you trying?

Comment: I am unable to add it to the PC as a printer

Comment: Can you use the Canon software to find the printer on your network, rather than relying on Windows to find it?

Answer (score -1):

Is your printer connected directly to your PC?
Apparently, Canon does not support bridged networks on your computer.
Their solution is to disable the network-bridge on your computer.